# Where to find a ROM dump for the Atari ST cartridge 'ACTION'

Tags: atari, game-cartridge, atari-st

Back in the day I owned a couple Atari ST, I used a cartridge based program for writing video games. It was called **"ACTION"** Does anyone remember this program or even better, know where I can get a ROM dump for my emulator?

Comment: ACTION! <-> **Atari ST** ???? Are you sure? ACTION! was a thing on the 8-bit Ataris only, afaik.

Comment: Definitely for 8-bit Atari only. I have an Action! cartridge.

Comment: Hmmm. I had ATARI XL also, I wonder if I am mistaking it being on the ATARI ST. It was a great program. Is there a ROM dump available for the 8-bit emulator? Which then leads me to the question, there was a game creator program for the ATARI ST that I used. Any ideas of what it was called? I think the DEMO files in it had a caractor of a Gorilla with a machine gun.

Comment: I think I just found my answer. STOS game creator.

Comment: Yes, STOS BASIC was the popular one for making games on the ST.  I had the Amiga version (AMOS) and you really could make some decent arcade-quality games with it.

Answer (score 3):

For the Atari 8-bit, not the Atari ST, everything you've asked for (and more can be) found at the [Action page at AtariWiki](https://atariwiki.org/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Action).

Answer (score 2):

Action! is a programming language for the Atari 8-bit line.  It was never ported to the Atari ST.

I can't find a ROM of the cartridge, but the Internet Archive does hold printed manuals for the language as well as its source code, which was released under the GPL by Action! author Clinton Parker.

- Manual (2018 edition):
  https://archive.org/details/ActionManual3rdRevisedEdition2018ByGBXL
- Source code: https://archive.org/details/ActionVersion36_SourceCode